# reference inner XML document using URI

Tags: xml, mpeg-dash

I have a xml document as below. I would like to keep the content of `AdaptationSet` in a separate file/document. Is it possible to do that and reference it somehow in the current document using an URI like the [`@id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#syntax-tokens-and-keywords) keyword works on JSON-LD?

```
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H3M1.63S" minBufferTime="PT1.5S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011"
type="static">
  <Period duration="PT0H3M1.63S" start="PT0S">
    <AdaptationSet>
      <ContentComponent contentType="video" id="1" />
      <Representation bandwidth="4190760" codecs="avc1.640028" height="1080" id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" width="1920">
      </Representation>
       </AdaptationSet>
   </Period>
</MPD>
```

Answer (score 0):

The MPEG-DASH spec allows the use of a limited subset of XML Linking Language (xlink) to reference remote elements, including AdaptationSet, assuming your player supports it.

dash.js, for example, has some support for this - see https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/blob/development/samples/ad-insertion/xlink.html